# Why was this question about tipping closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

Why close https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/151871/76132? there's a Tipping tag with 112 questions.

Chris H says I didn't address his question. Apologies – I thought this was obvious. I typed out reasoning, but my comment got deleted?

1. Travellers have to tip in Chinese restaurants in North America. 2. Chinese customs are different. Non-Chinese travellers probably don't know them. 3. This doesn't mean racism, but some Chinese tourists are known to be very unprofessional. See https://reddit.com/r/Chinesetourists/top/. I can't just take  the restaurant staff's word.

Look at these questions all open and tagged tipping. How are they on topic but not mine? They can be asked by local residents.

[Is tipping customary in London in a restaurant?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131097/is-tipping-customary-in-london-in-a-restaurant)
[Do hotel cleaning personnel have any benefit from leaving empty bottles in the room as opposed to returning them to the store?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140706/do-hotel-cleaning-personnel-have-any-benefit-from-leaving-empty-bottles-in-the-r)
[How to reward good service in Japan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148897/how-to-reward-good-service-in-japan)
[How much is customary to tip drivers in Georgia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151114/how-much-is-customary-to-tip-drivers-in-georgia)
[Is tipping mandatory at restaurants in Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150965/is-tipping-mandatory-at-restaurants-in-canada)

Comment: I asked you in the comments how that is a travel question. Your reply didn't actually address that at all, but just stated - as you have here - that there is a tipping tag with 112 questions. The fact that some other questions related to tips are also travel questions does not mean that every tip-related question is a travel question. I suggest you think a bit harder about whether your question actually has any relevance to travel, because I sure can't see any.

Comment: @chrish done in my post

Comment: no you haven’t. You’ve linked to a bunch of other tip-related questions which - unlike yours - all have fairly clear connections to travel. I really think you should try to explain what it is about **your** question that makes it travel related. And I mean *explain*, in your own words, *which part of your question* relates to travel; I **do not mean** point at the existence of other (really quite different) tip-related questions.

Comment: @ChrisH How do they "all have fairly clear connections to travel"?

Comment: they're mostly of the format "I am visiting <some destination OP is unfamiliar with>, what is the tipping culture there?". The other is about hotels. If you can't see for yourself how those questions are connected to travel, I have no idea what to tell you.

Comment: there may even be other questions which (unlike the ones you linked to so far) are in fact similar to yours, and have not been closed. I doubt it, but it is possible. But even if you do find one (or more), **this is irrelevant**. Sometimes questions fade from view before they get enough close votes. That does not mean they are on-topic, it merely means they slipped through the net. The existence of other questions will not make your question on-topic.

Comment: If you genuinely want to understand why your question has been judged to be off-topic, you should do what I've already suggested three times and **explain how you think your question relates to travel**. If we don't understand your logic we can't tell you where it goes wrong. In case it needs repeating, that means using your own words to **talk about your question and how it is related to travel**. Pointing at other questions is not an explanation, and is not helpful - they are not your question, and do not affect whether or not your question is on-topic.

Comment: the question was closed as being off-topic, you repeatedly complained about that but when asked what the connection to travel was you refused to provide any explanation, instead just linking to entirely dissimilar tip-related questions as if their mere existence makes every tip-related question on-topic. Asking you for an actual explanation is not "trolling", and I'm not going to accept such accusations. Especially when you make sweeping racist generalisations in the same comment.

Comment: @ChrisH I typed out my reasoning right above your comment. Now you accuse me – "you refused to provide any explanation"????

Comment: @ChrisH did you see my edit above?  i'm sorry if "Trolling" offended you. my reasoning got deleted.

Comment: as my previous (since deleted by a moderator) comment said: I'm not prepared to engage with you further as I do not believe you are acting in good faith.

Answer (score 9):

A comment under your question seems to explain the reasoning:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's purely about tipping decisions, not about tipping culture. – [Nean Der Thal 2 days ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151871/if-a-restaurant-manager-asks-you-to-tip-more-is-it-then-fair-to-tip-0#comment377334_151871)

This seems sensible to me. The question is opinion-based. Some will say it's reasonable not to tip, others will disagree.

From [the help center](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Travel Stack Exchange** is for **road warriors and seasoned travelers**.. If you have a question about …
>
> [..]
>
> and it's **not** about …
>
> - a question where every answer is going to be equally valid (eg 'What country in Europe should I visit?' (which would also be overly vague and broad))